# Bias in editing answer

Tags: discussion, edits, bias

I've been doing a lot of edit reviewing lately and I seem to be the only one actually taking the time to analyze everything before accepting / rejecting an edit. But that's for some other discussion.

While doing just that, I stumbled upon [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/142473) to an answer. The original answer mentions the acronym of a product name. The editor edited in the full name of the product and included a link to the product. Checking [the editor's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/255194/sean-kearney) revealed that he works for the company that makes said product (if it's not clear enough, check out [the first blog post](http://seankearney.com/post/Sitecore-Serialization-Format.aspx) on his linked site).

Now there's a kind of unwritten rule on Stack Overflow that stipulates that you should mention you work for a company when referring to one of it's products in an answer. Then again, that's not an answer.

In my opinion, this edit is okay, but I'd like to know what others thing about it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems OK to me, he has only written the full name. It's not that he changed the answer to point to his own employer. Checking his history reveals that he is participating just fine in the Stack Overflow community and doesn't spam.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion:

- If the edit improves the answer or question, then it is OK.
- If the edit does not improve the answer or question, then it is not OK.

The motive of the editor is irrelevant (in my opinion).  Of course, in practice, people will look and see if the user has participated elsewhere and in what capacity, and that's fine.  But ultimately, all that really matters is whether or not the answer or question is improved by the edit.